# Get variable from remote php function without allow_url_include on

Tags: php

i need to call one variable (*keyword*) from remote php file (config.php) --> server2
and to include in php function which is in another web server
i know by default php doesnt allow **inclusion**

is there any way around for me to get the variable without setting allow_url_include **on**

this is the function.php on server 1

```
<?php
include('config.php');

if ($_GET){
    $req_url = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    $page = substr($req_url, strrpos($req_url, '=')+1);
    $number = (int)$page;
    $xurl=('https://example.com/?q=' . $keyword .'');
    }

echo xurl;  
?>
```

and here's the config.php on server 2

```
    <?php
    $base="http://example2.com";
    $baseurl="http://example2.com/get.php?";
    $basejson="http://example.com/function.php";
    $keyword = "mountain";
    ?>
```

Comment: `include` is not possible. Your `php` scripts are executed on the local server before they are ever sent anywhere else. Thus, even if you were to use an URL you would only receive a blank file - no variable access. Instead - if there is no sensitive information on the `config.php` - create a `ini` file and then `parse_ini_file` which will give you an array. (not the best solution as if someone gets the link they could get that information). A better way to go is creating separate config files for each environment such as Laravel.

Comment: Hi @Samuel, this client side will be provide many different keyword by their own, providing separate config file will be limiting my client, and i dont know much about lavarel

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do that. It would be an extreme security gap.

If you have access to the remote webserver you may do an scp via exec and copy the file to your local server on each request. Or define a caching time and do it once every hour or whatever.

Comment: @steven this is for client and server and i want to hide the function.php code from client side

Comment: @pat ok. But you cannot do both. You have to make a decision. Hide it or Include it. You cannot do both at the same time. Included files are never hidden. If you like it like this you need to provide a API.

Comment: @steven yes, i will try to provide api then, thanks.